# Query containing special characters passed by pyodbc works differently in standalone ArcGIS script and toolbox

Tags: arcpy, pyodbc

I am passing few queries through pyodbc in my script to get data from Access database and write them to layers table. Everything was fine when I have been running script from PyCharm, but when I put it in toolbox and tried to run it in ArcGIS, queries containing national diactric characters stopped working. Here is an example of such query:

```
expression_2 = """SELECT F_ARODES.ARODES_INT_NUM, F_STOREY_SPECIES.SPECIES_CD, F_STOREY_SPECIES.SPECIES_AGE
            INTO fill_wydzielenia_2_temp
            FROM F_GROUP_CATEGORY INNER JOIN ((F_ARODES INNER JOIN F_SUBAREA ON F_ARODES.ARODES_INT_NUM = F_SUBAREA.ARODES_INT_NUM) INNER JOIN (F_AROD_STOREY INNER JOIN F_STOREY_SPECIES ON (F_AROD_STOREY.ARODES_INT_NUM = F_STOREY_SPECIES.ARODES_INT_NUM) AND (F_AROD_STOREY.STOREY_CD = F_STOREY_SPECIES.STOREY_CD)) ON F_SUBAREA.ARODES_INT_NUM = F_AROD_STOREY.ARODES_INT_NUM) ON F_GROUP_CATEGORY.AREA_TYPE_CD = F_SUBAREA.AREA_TYPE_CD
            WHERE (((F_ARODES.TEMP_ACT_ADRESS)=?) AND ((F_AROD_STOREY.STOREY_RANK_ORDER)=?) AND ((F_STOREY_SPECIES.SPECIES_RANK_ORDER)=?) AND ((F_GROUP_CATEGORY.SUPERGR_CAT_NAME)=?))"""

db_cursor.execute(expression_2, (True, 1, 1, u"grunty leśne zalesione"))
db_cursor.commit()
```

Created table "fill_wydzielenia_2_temp" is empty when script is run from ArcGIS, but is correctly populated when I run the script from an IDE.
I assume the argument with special characters must be treated differently, but I don't know the cause. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the character in code for its Python Unicode representation helped. It now works correctly.

```
db_cursor.execute(expression_3, (True, 1, 1, u"grunty le\u015Bne zalesione"))
```